# When can I upgrade from 17.10 to 18.04?

Tags: updates

I see that Ubuntu 18.04 is out already. I can't update from software & Updates( It says my system is up to date)(Yes,I've enabled notify for new ubuntu version). When I run do-release-upgrade -c ,It says no new release found. Is there any alternative way? Or is it not available for update yet?

Comment: Please refer to this link: [How do I update from 17.10 to 18.04LTS without update manager?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028579/how-do-i-update-from-17-10-to-18-04lts-without-update-manager-update-manager-ha)

Comment: @sluo6 by editing sources.list? Is it safe?

Comment: You don't need to edit sources.list for do-release-upgrade - that tool does all that for you. The other problem described in that link is possibly not related.

Comment: do-release-upgrades shows no new releases found

Comment: solved I had to add -d to do-release-upgrade ., I've upgraded succesfully. Thank you all

Comment: A limitation of this site makes it look like I voted to close it as a duplicate - I actually voted to close it as it's not going to be relevant anymore within a day or so of posting. The system tends to meld together people's reasons they voted to close. At any rate, I *don't* agree that's an acceptable duplicate of this question.